# Multiple ajax source at Datatable

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, datatable

i have a question. can we put multiple ajax source at datatable and show it only to one table ? i have many link source like "https://link1.com/prices/?Origin=+Origin+&Destinaton=+Destinaton" and "https://link2.com/prices/?Origin=+Origin+&Destinaton=+Destinaton" . and i can only show data from 1 source .

```js
var Origin = "<?php echo $Origin; ?>";
var Destinaton = "<?php echo $Destinaton; ?>";
var dataTable = $("#dtb_table").dataTable({
  'bProcessing': true,
  'bServerSide': false,
  'sAjaxSource': "https://link1.com/prices/?Origin="+Origin+"&Destinaton="+Destinaton,
  'columns': [
     { "data": "Moda" },
     { "data": "Service" },
     { "data": "Origin" },
     { "data": "Destinaton" },
     { "data": "Price" }
   ],
});
```

```html
<div class="box-body table-responsive">
  <table id="dtb_table" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Moda</th>
        <th>Service</th>
        <th>Origin</th>
        <th>Destinaton</th>
        <th>Price</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: you have an error?

Comment: if i only use 1 ajax source, i have no error . but i dont know how to show data from multiple ajax source

Comment: Maybe you can try another way to join multiple data into one request url.